# Error in installing google plugin for eclipse juno 4.2

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

I'm using Google App Engine, and I tried to install Google App Engine plugin in Eclipse Juno 4.2, but I got the error:

> could not find https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try only 'https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2' without 'GAE -', and it works for me.